# ElasticSearch: populating ip_range type field via logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm experimenting with the `ip_range` field type in ElasticSearch 6.8 (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/range.html) and struggle to find a way to load ip data into the field properly via **logstash**

I was able to load some sample data via Kibana Dev Tools, but cannot figure out a way to do the same via logstash.

### Index definition

```
PUT test_ip_range
{
  "mapping": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "ip_from_to_range": {
          "type": "ip_range"
        },
        "ip_from": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "ip_to": {
          "type": "ip"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Add sample doc:

```
PUT test_ip_range/_doc/3
{
  "ip_from_to_range" : 
  {
    "gte" : "<dotted_ip_from>",
    "lte": "<dotted_ip_to>"
  }
}
```

### Logstash config (reading from DB)

```
input {
  jdbc {
  ...
  statement => "SELECT ip_from, ip_to, <???> AS ip_from_to_range FROM sample_ip_data"
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "<host>"
  "index" => "test_ip_range"
  "document_type" => "_doc"
  }
}
```

### Question:

How do I get `ip_from` and `ip_to` DB fields into their respective `gte` and `lte` parts of the `ip_from_to_range` via `logstash` config??

I know I can also insert the ip range in CIDR notation, but would like to be able to have both options - loading in CIDR notation and loading as a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, finally figured out the logstash config.

I had posted about a similar issue [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-index-percolator-field-via-logstash-and-json-encode-filter/277860), which finally got me on the right track with the syntax for this use case as well.

```
input { ... }
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "[ip_from_to_range]" => 
      '{
        "gte": "%{ip_from}",
        "lte": "%{ip_to}"
       }'
    }
  }
  json {
    source => "ip_from_to_range"
    target => "ip_from_to_range"
  }
}
output { ... }
```

**Filter parts explained**

1. `mutate add_field`: create a new field `[ip_from_to_range]` with its value being a json string ( '{...}' ). It is important to have the field as `[field_name]`, otherwise the next step to parse the string into json object doesn't work
2. `json`: parse the string representation into a json object